# Upload images acces to path denied

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I seem to be having a problem when uploading images in asp.net.When I tryed to upload an Image I get this error:

> Access to the path 'D:\Projects IDE\Visual Studio\MyWork\Websites\Forum\Images\avatar\userAvatars\aleczandru' is denied.

I have set application pools Identoty to NETWORKSERVICE ando also added the NETWORK SERVICE account to the Images folder with full permision but I still get the same error.

This is my code:

```
private void addImageToApp()
{
    string path = "~/Images/avatar/userAvatars/" + User.Identity.Name;

    createPath(path);
    if( Directory.Exists(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(path)))
    {
        //try {
              UploadImage.SaveAs(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(path));
          //    MultiViewIndex.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
        //}catch(Exception ex)
        //{
          //     AvatarDetails.Text = ex.Message;
        //}  
    }
}

private void createPath(string path)
{  
    string activeDir = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Images/avatar/userAvatars");
    if( !Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(path)) )
    {
        string newPath = Path.Combine(activeDir, User.Identity.Name);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
    }
}
```

What else can I do to solve this problem?

**EDIT**

Hi at this point I have full permision control to the following USERS:

- Authetificated Users
- IUSR
- SYSTEM
- NETWORK SERVICE
- IIS_WPG
- Administrator
- USers

Is it posible that I need to set any configuration to IIS in order for this to work?

**EDIT**

I have messed around with SQL-SERVER for the last couple of days in order to make this work so I might have missconfigured something form what I understand NETWORK SERVICE is stored in SQL-SERVER master.db database.I seem to be having two network service logins may this be the problem?I remember when I first checked it I had none now I have two:

[image]

**EDIT**

This is the print with the permisions I added to the folder:

[image]

**EDIT : Complete error**

[image]

StackTrace:

[image]

Comment: Can you give some more details: Are you running this on the development webserver or IIS. And what version of .net / IIS are you using? Is the path created and no file uploaded or is also the path not created?

Comment: I am using .NET 4 and IIS 6.1.The path gets created using the username of the user.This part works.The part that does not work is when I try to save the file , I get acces denied error I will ost the entire error and stack trace.The error also appears if I runt it from visual studio not just from IIS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In method `CreatePath` you are creating folder 'D:\Projects IDE\Visual Studio\MyWork\Websites\Forum\Images\avatar\userAvatars\aleczandru'.

Then, you try to save the uploaded image with the filename 'D:\Projects IDE\Visual Studio\MyWork\Websites\Forum\Images\avatar\userAvatars\aleczandru'.

You can't have a folder and a file with the same name. If you try to do this, the OS will tell you access is denied.

[image: What happens if you try this in a command prompt]

I suppose you want to either create a filename inside folder `aleczandru`, or you meant to save the file as `aleczandru.png` or something in folder `userAvatars`.

Assuming your `UploadImage` is a [FileUpload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx) control, you can save the file to the user's folder using the original file name of the uploaded file.

```
UploadImage.SaveAs(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(
    Path.Combine(path, UploadImage.FileName)));
```

Comment: could you please show me an example on how I should do this I am kind of confused?

Comment: See updated answer. If it's still not clear, what is the complete path and filename you expect to get?

Comment: @Mert: I see. You did indeed. But I must say I didn't see what you meant at first. Now that you posted your comment I see your answer actually is the same, although more like a comment.
Nistor should decide if he wants to change correct answer to your answer (and see what he does with the bounty of course). He could even choose to make one answer correct answer and award the bounty to other answer.

Answer (score 4):

Pls make sure you have full filename with file extention in you path.

Comment: There would be no filename when creating a directory?

Comment: he is not having error while he is creating directory. as you see yellow screen he is getting error on save as method. and path doesn't have filename.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I thought the error was when creating the directory, not uploading the file.

Answer (score 1):

Ok... I have done this before for a project to implement a PUT method for http. I dont clearly remember it.. but some hints... if I were in my office I could tell you correctly. here are the hints

1. You need to add IIS_IUSRS to have access to the folder in windows.
2. Go to IIS admin console click the deployed site node, and set the permission for the same folder/website requests coming in... I dont remember the which category was it.. that settings pane will allow you to add/modify permissions for POST, GET and other verbs for that matter...  when you edit that, you should see options for Administrator, a particular user account, anonymous etc.

may be I will write back tomorrow... exactly how to do it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the group called users the permission to modify this directory (under security)

Comment: make sure this folder is not read only or under source control

Comment: Try to change the permission for built in users

Comment: all of the account that are added to that folder has full control to the folder

Comment: does this folder (D:\Projects IDE\Visual Studio\MyWork\Websites\Forum\Images\avatar\userAvatars\aleczandru) exist? or only the folder D:\Projects IDE\Visual Studio\MyWork\Websites\Forum\Images\avatar\userAvatars\ exist?

Comment: If you read the code I provided you will that if the folder does not exist it gets created

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out what user the asp.net upload page is running under. If you haven't changed it, and are not running under impersonation, it should default to the ASPNET user on the local machine. Whatever it turns out to be, give that user read/write permissions on the folder.

Comment: I've found I have to enable access for IUSR (assuming IIS)